# How cam I programatically get internet traffic from a web site in C# or C++?

Tags: c#, http

How do I programatically get internet traffic from a web site in C# or C++?

I mean, how can this be done without opening up a browser or a broswer control?

Additionally, there is some sort of plugin to a browser in IE and others where you can watch the communication from a browser to a server and back.  Does anyone know about this?