# How can I programatically get internet traffic from a web site in C# or C++?

Tags: visual-c++, c#-4.0, internet-explorer-8

How do I programatically get internet traffic from a web site in C# or C++?

I mean, how can this be done without opening up a browser or a broswer control?

Additionally, there is some sort of plugin to a browser in IE and others where you can watch the communication from a browser to a server and back.  Does anyone know about this?

Comment: When you say "get internet traffic," do you mean "make HTTP requests to the web server" or "determine how many people are visiting a site?"

Comment: Wow, that's broad. There are so many HTTP libraries out there it isn't funny. I think you need to look for an introduction to network programming, and then look into the many available HTTP (and HTML) libraries out there.

Comment: + This is a duplicate :: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4721236/482864

Comment: possible duplicate of [How cam I programatically get internet traffic from a web site in C# or C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721244/how-cam-i-programatically-get-internet-traffic-from-a-web-site-in-c-or-c)

Comment: @Soulseekah: Hopefully can mark the other as a duplicate. This one has more answers... And for that matter, I believe you can flag for mod attention duplicate.

Comment: Jeez, why did you ask this TWICE and accept two different answers?  I should merge, but then the person you selected as the answer in the other question would lose points...

Comment: Sorry, I did not know I added this twice.  I would think you could merge and still keep the points.  Our just remove the other post but keep the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for programmaticaly requesting web pages then you might check [httpwebrequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) in C#.

*Additionally, there is some sort of plugin to a browser in IE and others where you can watch the communication from a browser to a server and back. Does anyone know about this?*

you can check [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: fiddler is one option, but isn't there one that is a plug in right into IE?

Answer (score 2):

Look into cURL for C++ http://curlpp.org/
or if you want more low-level communication processing check socket programming and winsock. You'll connect to a server on a port and send a GET request, the server will respond with the HTML code if the page is an HTML, etc.

You will have to have some basic HTTP protocol knowledge though.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Answer (score 1):

Use the WebClient.DownloadString() or DownloadStringAsync() with the address of the web site.

Answer (score 0):

WebClient and HttpWebRequest can be used to communicated with servers without a browser

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx

Fiddler can be used to watch the browser communication

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Net.HttpWebRequest, which lets you send http get and http post requests.